# Adding a hyperlink in PHP that is being overriden

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

I have overridden the includes/no-results.php within my WordPress theme as follows:

```
<div class="entry">
<!--If no results are found-->
    <h2><?php esc_html_e('NO SUCCESS STORIES YET','Divi'); ?></h2>
    <p><?php esc_html_e('You could be the first! Request an appointment today.','Divi'); ?></p>
</div>
<!--End if no results are found-->
```

I would like to link the text "Request an appointment today" to the url of the Request an Appointment page and am not sure how to go about this.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `a` in `p` and write `href` with `php`

Comment: You can just take the PHP out of the <p> tag and write normal HTML. It is only in there to allow it to be Translatable.